# Search and sorting are not working in multiple DataTables in single page

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have 5 tables using DataTables in single page. The first table is working properly with search and sorting an items but the other tables are not working with it. Here's my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#itemList').DataTable();
    $('#itemListPending').DataTable();
    $('#itemListAccepted').DataTable();
    $('#itemListShipped').DataTable();
    $('#itemListDelivered').DataTable();

    //Partial Items
    $("#tbl_pending").load('@Url.Action("GetPendingOrders", "Admin")', function () { });
    $("#tbl_accepted").load('@Url.Action("GetAcceptedOrders", "Admin")', function () { });
    $("#tbl_shipped").load('@Url.Action("GetShippedOrders", "Admin")', function () { });
    $("#tbl_delivered").load('@Url.Action("GetDeliveredOrders", "Admin")', function () { });

});
</script>
```

I already search on the internet but nothing happens. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add your HTML?

Comment: Hi @MehdiDaustany, all the tables has an Id corresponding to the declared in script. It's just a normal table

Comment: Try below answer dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
let dt_columns = ["columns for table1", "columns for table2", "etc"];
let tables = [];
$('.table').each(function(i, el) {
    var dataSource = $(this).attr("data-ajaxsource");
    var columns = dt_columns[i];
     tables[i] = $(this).DataTable({
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": {
          "url": dataSource,
          "type": "POST",
          "data":{}
      },
      "columns": columns
    });
});

/* reload datatable if you want */
$("AnyEventHappenOnYourTables").change(function(){
  tables.forEach(function(el, i){
    el.ajax.reload();
  });
});
```

It means you have to fill tables by `@Url.Action("GetPendingOrders", "Admin")` list via ajax, by this way your `JQuery.DataTable()` will wait until action loaded.